# IE cutting my headings

Tags: internet-explorer, fonts, html-heading

url: http://carloshermoso.com/

IE is cutting the heading in my site. Only IE. Even if you change the font size. Any solutions?

```
#header { font-weight:700; margin:0 auto; max-width:980px; padding:25px 0 25px 0; text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000; width:80%; }

#mainContent h2 { -ms-filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7F000000,endColorstr=#7F000000); background:none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7F000000,endColorstr=#7F000000); font-weight:700; padding:10px; text-transform:uppercase; zoom: 1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an IE11 (maybe IE10 as well) rendering bug related to the text-shadow property applied to that text. I was seeing this as well and I've found at least one mention of it by somebody else:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/a37512ca-25bb-46a8-ab73-4536158ea9e6/text-shadow-css-code-causing-some-text-to-not-displaycutoff-in-internet-explorer-10?forum=iewebdevelopment